# Adjusting/controlling entire distribution for covariates

Tags: distributions, modeling, predictor, adjustment, controlling-for-a-variable

Suppose I have data on the number of views that Youtube music videos receive as of a fixed date. Let $Y_i$ represent the number of views that video $i$ has received by this date. I want to compare the entire distribution for $Y$ across music genres. In other words, I would like to overlay the genre-specific distributions of $Y$ into a single plot. The point of this exercise is to visualize how the distribution for one genre compares to the distributions of the rest.

However, suppose I know before hand that the number of views a video receives is affected by things such as date of release, gender of musician, etc. To improve my comparisons, I want to adjust my genre-specific distributions for differences in these covariates across genres. The idea is to compare genre-specific distributions that have been stripped of these influences. How can I do this? Is there a statistical technique that allows me to adjust the entire distribution (as opposed to a single summary statistic such as the mean) for such covariates?